# Laravel Input::GET doesn't work with Carbon

Tags: php, laravel-4, php-carbon

This is quite the interesting situation:

As per laravel's documentation, the `2nd` parameter of `Input::get()` returns a default if none is present.

Unfortunately this line throws an error "data missing" when `data-from` is missing, **despite** specifying a default:

`Carbon::createFromFormat('Y/m/d',Input::get('date-from','2015/01/01'))`

**Full Code:**

```
try
{
    $dateFrom = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y/m/d',Input::get('date-from','2015/01/01'));
}
catch(InvalidArgumentException $e)
{
    return Response::make($e->getMessage(),500);
}
```

However, if i do:

`Input::has('date-from') ? Carbon::createFromFormat('Y/m/d',Input::get('date-from')) : new Carbon('2015/01/01')`

It works perfectly.

The question is simply: why?

Comment: Works for me... you sure that is the line throwing the error?

Comment: What version of Laravel 4 are you running?

Comment: Currently on laravel 4.2.16 with the latest stable updates to all packages.

Comment: Added full code snippet. Carbon is throwing this error.

Comment: Could it be because the `date-from` field is getting passed as empty? This would explain why the default isn't getting picked up and the "data missing" error. If you do enter a date does it work as expected? If so then this is most likely why.

Comment: If you do `Carbon::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', '2015/01/01')` - does that work?

Comment: @javiervd - that is the whole issue. When `date-from` is empty, it should switch to `2015/01/01` due to the way `Input::get()` works.

Comment: Interesting I though the default only triggered if the field didn't exist not when it was empty.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange `Carbon::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', '2015/01/01')` works properly. And yea, the `date-from` field is empty. Still it should default. I tested all the scenarios, only the above one fails..

Comment: Let me just x-debug that :D into the rabbit hole i go..

Comment: I think @javiervd has the answer. `date-from` is probably set to `""` (i.e. blank) - therefore it is giving the command of `Carbon::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', '')`

Comment: Yeah just stepped into the code, if the `name` of the input is present, it will take its value, blank or not. Culprit in \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Arr.php Line 214.